# Server Error in '/login' Application

Tags: c#

I'm a C# newbie and I have encountered a problem.

My code below does not close the connection. (The connection remains open).  Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

```
    conn.Open();
    string checkuser = "select count(*) from UserDataT where Username='" + TextBoxUSERNAME.Text + "'";
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
    int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    if (temp == 1)
    {
        conn.Open();
        string checkPasswordQuery = "select password from UserDataT where Username='" + TextBoxUSERNAME.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand passComm = new SqlCommand(checkPasswordQuery, conn);
        string password = passComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" "," ");
        if (password == TextBoxPASSWORD.Text)
        { 
            Session["New"]= TextBoxUSERNAME.Text;
            Response.Write("Passwordi eshte korrekt.");

        }
        else
        {       
            Response.Write("Passwordi nuk eshte korrekt.");                
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
    else
    {
     Response.Write("Username nuk eshte korrekt.");        
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.

Comment: I assume that is an error message. What line produces it? does anything work? What does the debugger show?

Comment: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Comment: Line 25:         {
Line 26: 
Line 27:             conn.Open();
Line 28:             string checkPasswordQuery = "select password from UserDataT where Username='" + TextBoxUSERNAME.Text + "'";
Line 29:             SqlCommand passComm = new SqlCommand(checkPasswordQuery, conn);
 Line: 27

Comment: Please edit your question to add error information.

Answer (score 0):

Close `conn` after you are done with it if you want to open it again.

```
    conn.Open();
    string checkuser = "select count(*) from UserDataT where Username='" + TextBoxUSERNAME.Text + "'";
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
    int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

    conn.Close();

    if (temp == 1)
    {
        conn.Open();
        string checkPasswordQuery = "select password from UserDataT where Username='" + TextBoxUSERNAME.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand passComm = new SqlCommand(checkPasswordQuery, conn);
        string password = passComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" "," ");
        if (password == TextBoxPASSWORD.Text)
        { 
            Session["New"]= TextBoxUSERNAME.Text;
            Response.Write("Passwordi eshte korrekt.");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Passwordi nuk eshte korrekt.");
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
    else
    {
     Response.Write("Username nuk eshte korrekt.");
    }
```

**OR**

Only open and close `conn` once.

```
    conn.Open();
    string checkuser = "select count(*) from UserDataT where Username='" + TextBoxUSERNAME.Text + "'";
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
    int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

    if (temp == 1)
    {
        string checkPasswordQuery = "select password from UserDataT where Username='" + TextBoxUSERNAME.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand passComm = new SqlCommand(checkPasswordQuery, conn);
        string password = passComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" "," ");
        if (password == TextBoxPASSWORD.Text)
        { 
            Session["New"]= TextBoxUSERNAME.Text;
            Response.Write("Passwordi eshte korrekt.");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Passwordi nuk eshte korrekt.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
     Response.Write("Username nuk eshte korrekt.");
    }
    conn.Close();
```